# How to set a path with the PHPTAL::setPhpCodeDestination method on Windows?

Tags: php, zend-framework, xampp, phptal

I have project with Zend Framework.
I install xampp and download project.

However, I do not know how to set the path to phptal above. It is from what I noticed application.ini file and PHPTAL.php. In both is set to / tmp / and then the project does not work.
However, if you change to a different path is a project work without styles and layout's

How to set it up properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should solve your problem:

```
$phptal = new PHPTAL();
$phptal->setPhpCodeDestination('c:\\WINDOWS\\Temp\\'); // or whatever you want
```